# Remove special character from a string php

Tags: php

I have this string

```
<itcc-ci:somevariabletext contextRef="cntxCorr_i" unitRef="eur" decimals="0">2020265</itcc-ci:somevariabletext>
```

I want remove all characters and print only `2020265`.

How can I do that? I have used `str_replace` but it did not work. Any ideas?

I have use a `htmlspecialchars()` function, but now I have no idea. My string now is

```
&lt;itcc-ci:somevariabletext contextRef=&quot;cntxCorr_i&quot; unitRef=&quot;eur&quot; decimals=&quot;0&quot;&gt;2020265&lt;/itcc-ci:somevariabletext&gt;
```

Comment: Is this from an XML document? Consider using an XML parser.

Comment: use strip_tags to avoid tag..

Comment: How was `str_replace` used? Please add more context. `htmlspecialchars` is just changing the encoding, you don't want to do that.

Comment: Please share your entire XML response if it is XML element.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

My suggestion is that we take advantage of the fact that this number is between the '>' and '<' characters. If this is always the rule, then such code will help:

```
 $contextRef= '<itcc-ci:somevariabletext contextRef="cntxCorr_i" unitRef="eur" decimals="0">2020265</itcc-ci:somevariabletext>';

$startPos = strpos($contextRef, '&gt;') + strlen('&gt;');
$endPos = strpos($contextRef, '&lt;', $startPos);
$length = $endPos - $startPos;
$number = substr($contextRef, $startPos, $length);
echo  $number;
```

Comment: yes it's work. another question, if i want to grab the value of contextRef?

Answer (score 2):

It is XML, so parse it as XML.

```php
$x = '<itcc-ci:somevariabletext contextRef="cntxCorr_i" unitRef="eur" decimals="0">2020265</itcc-ci:somevariabletext>';
$d = new DomDocument();
$d->loadXml($x);

$list = $d->getElementsByTagName('itcc-ci:somevariabletext');
foreach($list as $node) {
    var_dump($node->textContent);
}
```

This will produce a warning since it is not a full document and is missing the namespace declaration. You should parse the *full* document and use XML operations to extract the data that you want, rather than picking fragments out of the middle.

See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Answer (score 0):

Your data is missing fundamental information. Assuming you have it all, and you just didn't share it here:

```
$input = '<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<some-root-tag xmlns:itcc-ci="some-missing-uri">
    <itcc-ci:somevariabletext contextRef="cntxCorr_i" unitRef="eur" decimals="0">2020265</itcc-ci:somevariabletext>
</some-root-tag>
';


$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($input);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('itcc-ci', 'some-missing-uri');
$value = (string)$xml->xpath('//itcc-ci:somevariabletext')[0];

var_dump($value);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/j5FbI#v8.2.4)